# Add hover to plot with multiple vertical bars Bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh

So I essentially followed the example on the bokeh documentation site about handling categorical data:

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/categorical.html

Which ended me up with this code (I simplified it a little):

```
# dictionary with data for making a figure
data = {'continents' : continents,
        '2016' : list2016,
        '2017' : list2017,
        '2018' : list2018 }


source = ColumnDataSource(data=data)

p = figure(x_range=continents, y_range=(0, 450), plot_height=250, title="University count per continent per year",
           toolbar_location=None, tools="")

p.vbar(x=dodge('continents', -0.25, range=p.x_range), top='2016', width=0.2, source=source,
       color="#c9d9d3", legend=value("2016"))

p.vbar(x=dodge('continents',  0.0,  range=p.x_range), top='2017', width=0.2, source=source,
       color="#718dbf", legend=value("2017"))

p.vbar(x=dodge('continents',  0.25, range=p.x_range), top='2018', width=0.2, source=source,
       color="#e84d60", legend=value("2018"))

p.x_range.range_padding = 0.1
p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
p.legend.location = "top_right"
p.legend.orientation = "horizontal"
```

Where the data column has 4 keys, with continents being the "categories" and 2016, 2017 and 2018 being a list of values corresponding to every continent in the continents list. So for example:

```
continents = ["Africa", "Europe"]
list2016 = ["1", "3"] 
list2017 = ["4", "2"]
list2018 = ["14", "3"]
```

So this basically that Africa had 1, 4 and 14 things of something in 2016, 2017 and 2018 respectively. Now what I would like to do is add hover to these different vertical bars so that if I hover of some bar it gives me the count numerically for that year/continent. Would this be possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `0.13`, you can give each glyph a `name` value then refer to that in tooltips as `$name`. Additionally you can look up from a column with that name by using `@$name`. You can also pass `tooltips` to `figure`  directly as a convenience. All together:

```
p = figure(x_range=continents, y_range=(0, 20), plot_height=250,
           title="University count per continent per year",
           toolbar_location=None, tools="hover", 
           tooltips="@continents $name: @$name")

p.vbar(x=dodge('continents', -0.25, range=p.x_range), top='2016', width=0.2, source=source,
       color="#c9d9d3", legend=value("2016"), name="2016")

p.vbar(x=dodge('continents',  0.0,  range=p.x_range), top='2017', width=0.2, source=source,
       color="#718dbf", legend=value("2017"), name="2017")

p.vbar(x=dodge('continents',  0.25, range=p.x_range), top='2018', width=0.2, source=source,
       color="#e84d60", legend=value("2018"), name="2018")
```

[image]

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks man! What exactly is the logic behind this? What does the $ mean?

Comment: The `@` denotes data from a specific column, e.g.. `@sale` means get data from a column "sales". The `$` variables are a handful of special, known variables, e.g. `$x` for the mouse x position, or `$name` for the hit glyph's "name" property value. The `@$name` combines the two -- look up a column, but use the *value* of the special variable `$name` as the column name (i.e. a level of indirection)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @bigreddot for the answer! I would like to add one important point that I struggled with. Make sure that the value of the `name` argument is the same as the value of the `top` argument. The `@$name` is using the string literal (i.e. the value of the `name` argument) to lookup the source for a column of that name. If there's a mismatch, then you get either the wrong values or `???` if  the value of the `name` doesn't match any column name in the source.

I've overlayed the popups in the image below:
[Bokeh vbar dodge unrendered values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keUDJ.png)